# How can we split a column with multiple values separated by "space" delimiter into multiple rows in Qlik using any logic

Tags: qliksense

I have one requirements as below. Suppose I have a column with below values

```
rowno             Column

1                 MS Teams slack skype
2                 slack
3                 skype
```

I want to split the first row as below

```
rowno          Column

1              MS Teams
1              slack
1              skype
2              slack
3              skype
```

How I can not use sub field function since it will split `MS Teams` to `MS ,Teams`. Instead can I use wildmatch? Please suggest how I can achieve this in Qlik Sense?

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do it in 2 parts... first to replace the MS Teams value with MS_Teams and then do the subfield. You could add another part to get rid of the _ at the end.

```
Table:
    Load
    rowno,
    subfield(Column_clean,' ') as Column;
Load
    rowno,
    replace(Column,'MS Teams','MS_Teams') as Column_clean
from source;
```

Comment: Hi, This works but problem is the column has multiple values that contain spaces. In this case how to write the script

Comment: It depends how many items there are - if you just need a few then you can nest the replace: `replace(replace(Column,'MS Teams','MS_Teams'),'Skype for Business','Skype_for_Business')`. If there are many then you might want to see if you can do something more clever with an inline table and a loop or a mapping table.